# Avoiding in Filter in AppEngine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, query-optimization

I have two Entities with me on Google DataStore:

A:

```
id,  
name,  
.... a lot of other columns
```

B:

```
id,  
Key(A, <id_of_A_record>) --> Reference Property A,  
URL,  
size  
... and more columns
```

I have a bunch of A ids with me and I want to query with those ids.
Now I am able to achieve this using

```
A_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B.all().filter('A IN', A_ids).fetch(None)
```

However, if there are 6 A_ids, there are 6 db calls, therefore beating the purpose of IN. Is they any way in which I can achieve this by avoiding the IN filter (too many DB calls)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `in` filter is actually just a convenience function provided by your ORM. Behind the scenes, it's doing a series of `OR`s to make it happen.

> The filter name in (value1, ..., valueN) is converted into (name = value1) OR ... OR (name = valueN) (also a DisjunctionNode)

https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/query.html#google.cloud.ndb.query.FilterNode

Even `OR`s aren't supported by datastore itself, it's just emulated by the client library:

> The nature of the index query mechanism imposes certain restrictions on what a query can do. Datastore mode queries do not support substring matches, case-insensitive matches, or so-called full-text search. The NOT, OR, and != operators are not natively supported, but some client libraries may add support on top of Datastore mode.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries

I think the client library performs `OR`s by launching separate queries, which is why you are seeing those 6 db calls. I don't think you'll be able to escape it without restructuring your data.